# AttributeError: module 'serial' no attribute 'serial'

Tags: python, pyserial

I am using:

```
Python v 3.9.2
Pycharm 2020.3.3
pyserial 3.5
```

Code snip:

```
#import serial
.
ser = serial.serial()
```

Error generated:

```
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'serial'
```

I have tried running the above with various combination of serial and pyserial installed, all unsuccessful.

I have also uninstalled/re-installed Python, with the same error.

Any other steps I can take?

Comment: Read the [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/shortintro.html#opening-serial-ports), it should be `Serial`

Answer (score 1):

The class `Serial` should be capitalized per the [pySerial docs](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html).

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial()
```

Comment: Serial is not a method, is a class

Comment: @FrancoMorero oops - not awake yet. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Serial is a [class in the pySerial API](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial), so the correct way is:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial()
```

Or:

```
from serial import Serial
ser = Serial()
```

Python is a case-sensitive language. This means, `serial` and `Serial` are not the same.

Comment: Thanks for those responses.  I get a  module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial' for the first suggestion.  I get ImportError: cannot import name 'Serial' from 'serial' (C:\repositories\scpi-rs-232\venv\lib\site-packages\serial\__init__.py)

Comment: run `pip install pyserial` inside the `venv`

Comment: Please forgive the 'newbieness', but I found a venv directory in both my project directory 
and in in my ..\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib directory.  For each location I did:  pip unistall pyserial  pip install pyserial  My script contians  from serial import Serial  I also now see two versions of Python on my box, 3.7 and 3.9.  Could this be causing the problem?

Comment: Please read the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html . You need to activate the virtual environment and inside it run pip.